# Magento 2 add custom value for Order Description in paypal?

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods, paypal, payment, paypal-express

[image]

The above image from Paypal. I change the value for **Description** or **Order Description** but I don't know where magento passing the information to the paypal popup.

I want to change the value for **Order Description** or **Description** in paypal.

By default value on paypal is **Shopping Cart** for both field.
I want to change that to some meaning full value that help me.

But I am not able to find the proper files to do so. Please provide suggestion where should I start.

I am using **paypal_express**

When I debug, I either land on Quote or Payment module be unable to find the file or location where I should override.

Comment: Can you share which method of paypal using?

Comment: I am using paypal_express

Comment: Okay, you have to override what feature? Do you want to add any custom value Or override any existing value?

Comment: Added a screenshot. I want to change some information that pass to paypal by default

Comment: okay thank you, can you specify section? is that change in delivery address OR any other?

Comment: Description or Order Description. You can check the screenshot.
The value is Shopping Cart by default.

Comment: Value you are getting in `Description` is `Shopping Cart`. You are using cart page checkout?

Comment: www.somedomain.com/checkout/#payment